# How to select values in oracle10g database?

Tags: oracle10g

For example my table contains a column 'skills'.
[image: oracle table]

i want to search the name who having skills in java and oracle.
I know its very simple,i am very new to oracle10g,please help me.
i tried like

```
select name from table_name where skills='java' or skills='java';
```

the name 'c' having skills in java and html,how can i select ?

```
select name from table_name where skills='java,html';
```

i dont know which method i wanna use,please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return any name that has java in its skills list.

```
select name from table_name where ','||skills||',' like '%,java,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name from table_name where skills like '%java%' or skills like '%oracle%';
```

That will give you names who have skills in java or oracle. If you want names that have both at the same time, change the "or" for "and".

Answer (score 1):

as shown in your table if you want to select names whose skills are either java or oracle you can do   select name from table_name where skills like '%java%' or skills like '%oracle%'   this will select all the names whose skills contains java or oracle